# Copy shell script and preserve permissions

Tags: bash, permissions, distribute

I have a small shell script that starts a program when I double-click it. (I have set the permissions to allow executing the script).

I want to be able to copy that script to another computer so that the new user can double-click it without needing to know anything about chmod or permissions. But I can't find out how to preserve the execute permission when I copy the file.

I can usually find answers with Google but this has me defeated - I guess I am not expressing my question properly.

Thanks

Comment: I seem to have stumbled on the answer. I was losing the executable status because I was copying the shell script onto a FAT formatted USB stick. By using TAR as suggested below, the status was preserved if I extracted the file with Archive Manager without using TAR.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rsync` or `tar`.

```
rsync -p file user@host:destdir
```

plus other options you might need.

Or

```
tar cvzf file.tar file
```

then copy (or email, etc.) `file.tar` to the other machine and extract the file:

```
tar xpvzf file.tar
```